# Can I cut a circuit board and will it still work?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have a pc usb and front panel audio circuit board, and I only plan on using the audio connectors. Can I cut off the USB ports part of the board and still have functional audio ports? The usb does not connect to the audio connectors on the board.[image: Circut Board]

Comment: Certainly looks like you could.

Comment: It appears that the PCB might only be a physical support for the USB sockets, but I can't tell from the side shown in the photo. Do the cables to the USB sockets go directly to the sockets without going via the PCB?

Comment: I just want this to show up in the relevant links: [Cutting an IC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182700), [Cutting a board](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1151), [Dremling a board](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93624/what-are-the-dangers-of-cutting-pcb-with-dremel)

Comment: @AndrewMorton the wires go into the usb socket

Answer (score 10):

General rule of thumb, no. Some PCBs have hidden inner layers which can hide circuitry. Even two layer boards have highly interconnected traces.

In your case though, the board is nothing more than wire to connector. There is seemingly no hidden gotchas. So the answer is most likely you will have no issues.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely. You should try to maintain the same grounding (looks like it takes place through the mounting holes as well as the black wire). The two mounting holes are both connected together, so one will suffice for electrical grounding purposes.

Arrows point to places where the ground plane is connected off the board.

[image]